# How to identify the current activity come from which activity?

Tags: java, android

In android app, contains A B C & D four activities, we can go to D Activity in two ways through B and C. while i am in D Activity how to identify which Activity i came from B or C?

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry. There is no built-in mechanism, You can set Boolean in your Intent's Extras to verify caller activity.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.getComponent().getClassName());
```

see if it helps